# Jira Cloud federating

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm running two Jira Cloud instances and two Confluence Cloud instances which need to see each other's project and issues. This seems to work fine for the Server version of Jira (if I may believe the documentation) but I'm unable to make it work for the Cloud version.

I'm interested in having a full integration for the unified activity stream, remote issue and project links, etc. Even with the full application link between both Jira's and both Confluence's it seems to not fully work like the documentation specifies it should. The documentation also states that if you set up the application link that you don't have to have duplicate users across all instances but that also does not seem to work.

What I'm seeing right now is that Jira's are unable to see each other's issues and or project and that one Confluence instance can see other Jira instance and can list all the issues but only if my account exists in both instances.

Is there a way of having multiple Cloud instances which can work together in a unified way without using any add-ons? I have spent quite a lot of time on this and also have looked through a lot of posts on StackExchange and other communities for answers.

[image: Jira - Application Link Example]

[Federating Jira - managing multiple instances](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/federating-jira-managing-multiple-instances-961257360.html)

Comment: Have you contacted the Atlassian support team?...

Comment: No, I did not @Attie. That's because their contact form just redirects me back out of the form for not being logged-in, while I am logged in. From what I've seen their response time can also be pretty slow. The following link redirects from https://support.atlassian.com/contact to https://support.atlassian.com for not being logged in.